# How to subtract military time between days with datetime module

Tags: python, datetime

I am working on a time lapse program and I would like to be able to pause overnight over multiple days.  I am using military time and when I try say 18:00:00 as pause start and 08:00:00 as pause end I get a negative number.  I could probably take the difference between 24:00:00 and 18:00:00 and 0:00:00 and 08:00:00 and add them to get the answer, but I'm wondering if there is something I'm missing in the datetime module that would allow me to do this?

```
from datetime import datetime

pause_start=input('Enter pause start time as 24 hrs (hh:mm:ss): ')
pause_end=input('Enter pause end time as 24 hrs (hh:mm:ss): ')
pause_start=datetime.strptime(pause_start, '%H:%M:%S')
pause_end=datetime.strptime(pause_end, '%H:%M:%S')

total_pause_time=(pause_end-pause_start).total_seconds() 
print(total_pause_time)

input:18:00:00
input:08:00:00
output:-36000.0
```

I tried an input of 25:00:00 and received an error saying time data did not match format '%H:%M:%S' therefore I believe it is being read correctly as military time.

Comment: Just add 24 hours to the result to get what you want.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice:  Thanks for the input.  I just find it hard to believe there is not a way to do it within the datetime module.

Comment: See my answer. If you want to use the datetime module, you need to set the relative dates correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are missing, is that you are calculating with times on the same day. So you are subtracting the later time from the earlier time which gives a negative result. I see two solutions:

1. Add 24 hours to the final result to get the correct offset.
2. Create `datetime` objects so that 18:00:00 is today and 08:00:00 is tomorrow morning. Then subtract the dates.

Comment: Yeah, I know it's being considered on the same day, but my problem is the time lapse is for many days and I don't want to have to enter in every day.  I am hoping to be able to just have the user input the time start and time end and use that each day.  Just adding 24 hours to the final result may be the only way to go.

Comment: @kurt You do not need to enter many days. Just use today and tomorrow. Or any two consecutive days.

Comment: @kurt Alternatively add one day to pause_end of it is earlier than pause_start.

Comment: @Kurt all of these solutions have a common theme. If the end time is an earlier time than the start time, you must treat it as the following day.

Comment: I appreciate all your answers.  I was not aware of the today/tomorrow option.  It seems like there is always some 'easier' solution built into the modules.